# Video codecs on IGEL clients? Or HTML5 Video Tag?

Tags: html, video, codec

I have a difficult problem. I have a python web application that creates a HTML5 Video Tag like it's done in this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay

It's working fine in Firefox! BUT: I have a IGEL Client solution with Firefox 52.7.2 and there I get the error message "Video format or MIME type is not supported". But I CAN play the video directly in the IGEL Firefox Browser with the URL.

Anyone with an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: I’m guessing IGEL does not include and h.264 decoder/license.

Comment: I think it has this license... otherwise it will be not possible to play the video directly in browser or am I wrong?

Comment: The browser could have its own license.